# Subset of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset

I have a `data` like this:

```
data <- data.frame (grp= c("on_1","off_2","on_3","off_4","on_5"),
                    duration=c(40,30,40,20,20))
```

Every values of `grp` is either on_* or off_* , where * is a natural number.
What I want to do is to divide `data` into two groups: on and off.

The exact numebr of * is not important to me. My expected output should look like this:

```
data_on<-data.frame(duration=c(40,40,20))
data_off<-data.frame(duration=c(30,20))
```

I tried to use `subset` for doing that.
I tried this:

```
data_on<- subset(data, grp= 'on_*')
```

But it gives the result not I wanted.

Comment: subset(data, grepl("on_[0-9]+", grp))

Comment: Try: `data[startsWith(data$grp, "on"),]`

Comment: Two comments work to me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using the tidyverse package:

```
    library(tidyverse)
    
    data <- data.frame (grp= c("on_1","off_2","on_3","off_4","on_5"),
                        duration=c(40,30,40,20,20))
    data = as_tibble(data)                    
    
    data = data |> mutate(group = str_split_fixed(grp,"_",n=2)[,1])
    
    data_on = data[data$group=="on",] |> select(-group)
    data_off = data[data$group=="off",] |> select(-group)
```